# What is the narrowest tire you would use for commuting?

Tags: tire, commuting-bike

Speed isn't so much of a factor, obviously, but the lower the rolling resistance the less sweaty I am when I get there. Then there's flats to consider. Basically the tire has to never get them because I can't be late. So what size would you ride?

Comment: Why would you want it to be as narrow as possible? Narrower implies more aerodynamic and *greater* rolling resistance, as well as more fragile. So narrow is only a benefit if your speed, and the aerodynamics of you and of the rest of your equipment, is such that the aerodynamics of your tires are relatively significant. (Please correct me if I'm mistaken).

Comment: @Geoff - Welcome to Bicycles.SE, and thanks for posting! This question *might* lead to better answers if you qualified it, what kind of roads you commute on, what kind of speed you maintain, and so on.

Comment: Please don't forget to say *why* that's the size. It's fine if "my favourite tyre X only comes in 26.24mm so that's the size", but just saying 37/82 inches is not helpful.

Comment: @Geoff - Neil has a good point. A commute through calm, nicely paved residential streets is much different than a commute through gritty, industrial/urban streets. Anyhow, other than the particular bike/rims, my choice of tire depends a lot on _where_ I'll be commuting.

Comment: @ChrisW: How does a narrower tire equate to greater rolling resistance? And how can that be true while simultaneously allowing greater speed and aerodynamics? If I'm wrong, I'm wrong, but the reason road bikes generally run narrow, high pressure tires is to benefit from lower rolling resistance. It allows higher speeds, with less effort.

Comment: @zenbike Rolling resistance is energy spent deforming the tire. For any given rider weight and given tire pressure, a narrower tire will deform deform more than a wider one. Narrow tires improve aerodynamics: which at high speeds (but only at high speeds) is more important than rolling resistance.

Comment: @ChrisW: Not true. Rolling resistance is energy spent moving a deformed patch of tire rubber over a surface. For any given rider weight and given tire pressure, a narrower tire will deform deform more than a wider one, proportionally, but will still have a smaller physical patch of rubber on the road, which will require less effort to roll over that surface. Aerodynamics are a minor consideration in the everyday use road wheel. It is true that aerodynamics will play a very small part in the resistance of a wheel moving forward at low speed. Narrow tires do not increase rolling resistance.

Comment: @zenbike - "smaller physical patch of rubber" - It will be narrower but longer: for a given weight and pressure, the total area of contact must be similar (e.g. 200 lb riding on tires at 200 psi must have 2 square inches of contact with the road). See http://www.schwalbetires.com/tech_info/rolling_resistance You're partly right in that wider tires are often at lower pressure, and knobblier or with a deeper tread pattern. Anyway, my tires are 32 at up to 100 psi and they're OK by me. See also pages 15 through 17 of [this IHPVA research paper](http://www.ihpva.org/HParchive/PDF/hp50-2000.pdf).

Comment: I'll look in to your papers, but on a practical level, the structural design of a tire controls how far the tire can spread, and the curve of the wheel limits the fore and aft spread. So I don't see how a 2.5 inch tire can have the same footprint on the ground as a 23c tire. In addition, most tires are limited by volume to maximum pressures. Meaning the wider the tire, the lower the designed (and safe)pressure. So if you are accurate about the contact patch at equal pressure with equal weight, which is possible, then the real world still sneaks back in.

Comment: A wider tire requires more effort to move forward in practice. It also has a larger physical contact with the round, and so, given similar tread designs, more traction. A narrower tire, btw, has the benefit of not having the surface area to hydroplane at pedal achievable speeds. In the case of a 32c tire, you might have enough traction for a v brake or a disc, and a disc would be better than a V-brake. But it would be bare minimum, and I wouldn't recommend it as an option for an unskilled rider, since it would require a lot more skill to modulate the brake given the linear design.

Comment: @zenbike I agree that it's counter-intuitive. Anyway, yes I do have hydraulic disk brakes, which work very well IMO: my bike (and this question) is about commuting, i.e. all weather including wet, and in traffic. When it's wet I don't think I go fast enough to hydroplane, and the tires do have some tread (not knobs).

Comment: I'm not saying it's counter intuitive. I'm saying that the situation you describe, of equal pressure tires with very dissimilar widths doesn't happen in the real world. This question is very much a real world question.

Comment: I run 100psi in my 35s.  Many people don't run that in 28s.  While tire pressure *tends* to increase as the tire gets narrower, it's not a hard and fast rule.

Comment: Clearing up a couple misconceptions here: 1) Contact patch size is a factor of total weight and tire PSI, by definition. The variable that changes is the shape of the contact patch, the effect of which is excellently illustrated [in this Bicicletta article](http://www.bicicletta.co.za/Downloadable%20docs/Rolling%20Resistance%20Eng%20illustrated.pdf). 2) Bicycles cannot realistically hydroplane. A hydroplaning rule of thumb is that hydroplane velocity in MPH can be approximated as 10*sqrt(PSI). On a snowbike at a ridiculously low 10psi, you'd need to get up to 32mph to risk hydroplaning.

Comment: Yep, narrow tires don't have significantly less rolling resistance than wider tires inflated to the same pressure.  And on a soft surface the wider tires actually roll easier.  The theoretical advantages of narrower tires are lower weight and less wind resistance. (Plus, of course, many guys think narrow tires look sexier, but these are, of course, guys wearing spandex, so take that for what it's worth.)

Comment: Another observation: I recall going on a week-long "loaded" tour with ~250 other cyclists a couple of decades ago.  I had a modestly priced touring bike, and there were other bikes of all descriptions, but a couple of dozen riders had road bikes with tires that were 1" and narrower.  These guys had flats like they were going out of style, many of them blowouts.  In several cases the narrow tires experienced blowouts just laying in the sun at the noon lunch stop.

Comment: A couple of decades ago? I wonder if tire tech has changed any in 20 years? I know my bike is the exact same model as my dad's bike was...

Comment: Certainly tire technology has improved a bit since then.  If nothing else, better cord material.  But a narrow tire really isn't intended to carry an extra 50 pounds of camping gear.

Answer (score 11):

For my commuting needs, I use [Continental Gatorskins](http://www.mec.ca/Products/product_detail.jsp?PRODUCT%3C%3Eprd_id=845524442586337&FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374302693841) 700x28c.  I also use [Mr Tuffy liners](http://www.mec.ca/Products/product_detail.jsp?PRODUCT%3C%3Eprd_id=845524442497945&FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374302693707) to help protect against punctures.  Using this combination, I haven't had a flat in 2 years.  Before going to this combination, I would get about 1 flat a month.  I travel about 14 km a day, 5 days a week, April to the end of November.

I recommend that you leave enough time in your commute to change a flat if need be.  For me, this is only about 10 minutes. Your time may vary.  My job is such that it's not a big deal if I'm a few minutes late.  If your job requires you to be right on time, you may have to sacrifice being early on the off chance you do get a flat.

Also, ensure that your tires do have enough air in them. If you use skinny tires, a lot of flats come from snakebite flats, caused by not enough air pressure.

Answer (score 10):

Personally I prefer the [Schwalbe Marathon Plus tyres](http://www.schwalbetires.com/node/1323) in a sensible width, 28 will do nicely or 1.5 (instead of 1.35) if using MTB or folding bike. To the pressure written on the sidewall, checked weekly for embedded glass and correct pressure.

The likelihood of getting flats on properly maintained Marathon Plus is practically zero. On every other tyre brand that I have tried this has not been the case, even if they come with a guarantee. With the Marathon Plus you can go out of your way to deliberately go through glass, for all other tyres glass is akin to Kryptonite.

The truth about the commute is that you learn every bump on the road but there is a lot of traffic and you have to be properly prepared to ride through the rough if you are to make good time.

On the commute it does take me 20 minutes to fix a flat. That is with correct tools and fresh tube. If I get two flats and have to stick on a patch (separate incident) it still takes 20 minutes. Notionally I can fix a tyre quicker than that but in practice this is not the case.

I don't leave 20 minutes earlier just in case I get a puncture, so long as it does not happen too often one can call ahead. Motorists in their cramped-yet-huge tin boxes are regularly a lot later than that.

Answer (score 7):

Tire size is not a sure indicator of flat resistance.   As Kibbee notes, proper inflation pressure, road character, riding style.... All factors.

I rarely get flats; can't remember when I had one last riding on the road.

However, they are as inevitable as anything else in life.   A good, durable 28mm tire is nice compromise between super-skinny "racing" tires and something you might put on a hybrid.

Avoid tires with tiny little cuts or "sipes", these tend to trap road debris and it will gradually work it's way through the casing.   Check pressures frequently, don't use super-light-weight tubes, etc. Watch the road!  Potholes, new pavement seams, broken glass and such from auto accidents (or car theft!) are all hazards that can generally be avoided.
And carry everything you need to fix a flat....Just in case.

Comment: "I rarely get flats" -- You just had to go and say that! :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm crazy but I use plain road (700/18s or 700/20s) tires. They are Kevlar reinforced though...

Comment: Nope, not crazy. Pretty much what I do. Cheap, kevlar reinforced road tires are widely available.

Comment: interesting... any specific brand/model?

Comment: @r00fus: I believe they are Michelin tires of some description, though I didn't buy them for a brand specifically.

Answer (score 2):

700c x 28 are the narrowest tires/tyres I would run for commuting. 
I would also recommend kevlar tires/tyres. The last thing you want is to try an repair a flat on the way to work. On the way home is still annoying but without the time obligation it is a little more tolerable.

Answer (score 1):

My bike (2010 Kona Dr Dew) came with 700x32 Continental Contact tires.

I've had the bike for 3.5 months so far: i.e. about 160 hours of commuting.

I've had 1 flat so far (front tire): caused by an impressively sharp, 3/4 inch nail through the tire. I don't know what tire could withstand that. When the bike tech replaced the tube for me (my first flat: I wanted to watch how he did it) I asked whether it had Slime in it and he said no: it's too heavy.

I don't always bother to avoid bumps and cracks and small pot-holes: apparently the wheels can take it.

The tires are OK on snow, too, going a bit cautiously; though not on ice.

They say 85 psi on the side. I try to inflate them to 95..100 psi each weekend, and they measure at 80 psi by the next weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I use a 23mm Continential GP4000S on the front. I love these tyres. They're super sticky and I've never had one slip out(!!)

On the back I'm trialling 23mm Continental Gatorskins. They are cheaper and since the rear wears out so much faster than the front I'm hoping they'll still grip well but not cost me too much. So far I've been riding on it for about 3 weeks and have had no trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The reason road bikes generally run narrow, high pressure tires is to benefit from lower rolling resistance. It allows higher speeds, with less effort.

I run Schwalbe Ultremo DD tires in 23c. They have excellent, sticky feeling traction, roll fast and smooth, and use a high Thread per Inch casing which helps with flats, as well as having a Kevlar anti flat layer built into the rubber surface. The DD stands for Double Defense.

It's always a fine balance between flat protection and ride quality. But tire width is not a major concern, assuming you're using tires appropriate to your bike and your riding style.

Comment: Of course, as stated above, tests show that narrower tires DO NOT have lower rolling resistance, at a given tire pressure.

Comment: At the same pressure, with the same rider weight. Which is not generally the case, because the higher the volume (width) on a tire, the lower the permitted pressure in general. And I was speaking of the difference between a wide, (1.5" or greater tire) and a narrow (23 or 25c tire).

Comment: But, as I pointed out, I run my 35s (1.38") at 100psi.  Many 28s are not rated higher, and something narrower than 28 is likely too fragile for commuting.

Comment: I commute regularly on 23c Tufo Tubular clinchers, and a set of Mavic Ksyrium Elite wheels. There is no such thing as too fragile for commuting. BTW, my tires? They are rated up to 220 psi. So don't assume that what you run is what everyone runs. I didn't make assumptions about what you were running, but you are assuming that I must agree with your choices. Also, if a standard road tire is not more efficient rolling, why does every UCI Pro team run the same, narrow profile? And please don't try the aerodynamics argument The benefit there is tiny compared to direct friction resistance.

Comment: As far as being too fragile to commute on, the main benefit of a wider tire is comfort on the ride. And they are more comfortable. That's why I run tubbys. They allow a faster smoother ride with a good comfort feel as well. Yes, it is a pain if I get a flat. But  don't, very often.

Comment: A wider tire is actually more likely to flat on certain types of road debris, like glass, because the wider contact patch allows the tire to deform around the debris, rather than kicking it away from the tire, as a narrower, higher pressure tire sometimes will. Of course, you are far more likely to pinch flat on a narrow non-tubular tire. So it isn't necessarily a benefit to extol. And while a tubby flats least often of all, if it does, you must replace the tire, not just a tube; I don't often recommend them for commuting. Just don't assume you have all the info. Not even I know everything :)

Comment: Keep in mind that once the PSI of the tire exceeds the PSI of the surface it's rolling on, resistance goes up, not down.  If you always ride on concrete then you can probably run 500 psi tires, but warm asphalt is probably closer to 100 psi.

Comment: Yes, if you ride on soft material, there will be more resistance. But, generally, unless you ride in 50c weather, consistently, then you are unlikely to have that problem on a road bike.

Comment: I've ridden on asphalt where I could feel the resistance with 1.25" tires on a warm day.

Comment: On a road bike. Which will not have 1.5" tires. And you should discuss that with the RTA in your town. We have asphalt roads, and 50c temps regularly, and I've never had the asphalt create a resistance issue. Unless it was fresh laid uncured paving...

Comment: It does depend on the age of the asphalt, but you can feel it easily in 6-month-old asphalt, and to some degree in asphalt that is 2-3 years old.  After that the stuff sets up pretty well.  (Note that I have polio-weakened legs and thus I'm fairly sensitive to minor differences in rolling resistance that others wouldn't notice.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously a lot depends on how far you travel and what the roads are like -- long distances over smooth suburban highways you want a bit narrower tire than for shorter distances or rougher, more urban streets.  But generally there's no point in going narrower than about 28 -- the savings in rolling/wind resistance would only be of interest to a racer -- and likely there'd be little advantage in going below 35 or so, if the route is at all rough.  Just be sure to keep your tire pressure up in the 80-100 range, near the top of the sidewall rating (something that also is important to prevent snakebite punctures).

What you definitely DO want is Kevlar-belted tires.  The puncture resistance of Kevlar tires is 5-10 times greater than standard tires, especially in the narrower, lighter sizes.  My current tires (35mm Kevlar-belted touring tires) have 3000-5000 miles on them and have never had a puncture.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that tire weight will affect the amount of work you have to do. It's most noticeable when changing from worn to new tires, but I'm kind of regretting fitting 28s because my old 25s were lighter. You have to maintain the rotating inertia of your tires, so it's not just rolling resistance, but also tire and rim weight that will affect the effort you will have to expend to maintain speed. This higher inertia will also make your bike more stable and slower to turn in. Bigger tires basically allow you to be more comfortable. Taller sidewalls, more available flex, and you can run slightly lower pressure and still avoid flats. I'm a big guy and I don't think 28s are really necessary, but they will increase the rigor of your workout, which is why I'm leaving them on. If you want to breeze quickly through your commute, you'll be fine with smaller tires

Comment: Welcome to [Bicycles.SE] @VWWV. The rotating inertia you mention costs no effort to maintain. That's why it's called inertia. It does take effort to get it moving though.

Answer (score 0):

Using 23mm tires on commuter for several years and feeling excellent, don't see any need to increase the size. Always commuting on asphalt only. Very seldom getting out on gravel and it is not that bad too.

Used Kenda, Panaracer, Michelin (Pro3 and Pro4) and Continental (4000). Michelin remain the distant favourite among all - the most sticky and comfortable tires.

During the last 5 years got only two flats. The first one was on Kenda tires - they were not good anyway, and the second on Panaracer, because tires were work out to the point of exposing large portions of wireframe.